# How to use nested values from secrets.json Azure's App Service Configuration

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-configuration

In my app's secrets.json file, I have the following section.

```
"Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "AzureTableStorage", 
        "Args": {
          "storageTableName": "Logging", 
          "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=xxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am attempting to deploy to Azure and have added the keys to my app service's configuration like this.

```
  Serilog__WriteTo__Name
  Serilog__WriteTo__Args__storageTableName
  Serilog__WriteTo__Args__connectionString
```

However, the application will not start (just shows an errror: "If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.") if I use either of the two longer keys.  I have another setting named `CosmosConnectionSettings__ContainerName` which works fine, so it seems to be a problem with the nesting rather than they key lengths.

The app service is configured to use Linux.

Is there a better way to approach this, and is this limitation documented anywhere?

Comment: I dont think its an issue with the config, did you try to check via Kudu?

Answer (score 0):

**I think it's not the nesting's fault.**

**I have test it on my side, here is my `secrets.json` file:**

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": {
      "Name": "AzureTableStorage",
      "Args": {
        "storageBlobName": "1.jpg",
        "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXX;AccountKey=XXX;"
      }
    }
   
  }
}
```

**And I write the value to the endpoint page like this:**
[image]
**Here is the Appsettings in my configuration on portal:**
[image]

**The Appsettings I set works well on azure web app.**
[image]

**My suggestion is:**

1. **Check how you use the key `AzureTableStorage` and `connectionString` in your scripts.**
2. **Test your project on IIS.** Actually if it works well on IIS, it should work well on Azure.